# What is the difference between Type Alias and Type Definition in Go?

Tags: go, type-alias, type-definition

Type alias:

```
type A = string
```

Type definition:

```
type A string
```

What is the difference between them? I can't understand from spec

Comment: Mean when i use type A = string, so A will exactly behave like string, and can do stuff that can do with string type without any type casting, like :-  var p A = "sfsdf"; p + "sdfds" works ? and in type A string, a new type is created, ?

Comment: Both forms are *type declarations*, the 1st form is using "alias declaration", the 2nd form is using "type definition".

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/jDiilL424d8

Comment: Type aliases serve no purpose during "programming", there is literally nothing what they do. They become useful during large scale refactoring of code. You'll find the lively debate online which happened prior to their introduction. You basically never need them (and you should _not_ use them!) until you need them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`type A = string` creates an alias for `string`. Whenever you use `A` in your code, it works just like `string`. So for example, you can't define methods on it.

`type A string` defines a new type, which has the same representation as `string`. You can convert between an `A` and `string` at zero cost (because they are the same), but you can define methods on your new type, and reflection will know about the type `A`.

For example (on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/krGQVv-K42x))

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A = string
type B string

func main() {
    var a A = "hello"
    var b B = "hello"
    fmt.Printf("a is %T\nb is %T\n", a, b)
}
```

Output:

```
a is string
b is main.B
```

Comment: Alias only for  compile time ? @paul-hankin

Comment: I don't believe there's any representation of the alias in the runtime reflection data, so it can be thought of as a compile-time alias. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @PaulHankin Actually, you can define methods on type alias, You just can't do that in this particular case. Please, see my answer

Comment: @PaulHankin Ah, sorry, misread it. `like string. So for example, you can't define methods on it` -- i would suggest to rephrase that for clarity.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin Or you could say that you can't define methods on the type alias, but you can sometimes define methods on the original type using the alias. I think what I wrote is accurate (and helpful in the context of the question), but I agree that it doesn't cover all the edge-cases.

Comment: @PaulHankin is my understanding correct: type definition is like forking. The new type has the same memory layout (fields) as the forked type, which allows one to be converted to the other. However, the new behavior (methods) we define on the forked type won't be available on the fork, and vice versa

Answer (score 8):

To be clear on terms, these both are [type declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations).

```
type A = string
```

This is called alias declaration. I.e. you creating an alias to a type. Basically, there's no difference between type and alias. You can define methods on alias and they will be available for initial type instances. [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/UtA4yOBKE3L):

```
type A struct {}

type B = A

func (B) print() {
    fmt.Println("B")
}

func main() {
    a := A{}
    b := B{}

    a.print()  // OUTPUT: B
    b.print()  // OUTPUT: B
}
```

Although, in your particular example `type A = string` you can't define methods on it, because string is non-local type(there was a [proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21401) to add ability to create methods for non-local types but it got rejected).

Your second case `type A string` is type definition. Basically it's creating new type that has all fields of original type, but not it's methods. [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/d5qLXR4KGRs):

```
type A struct {}

func (A) print() {
    fmt.Println("A")
}

type B A

func (B) print() {
    fmt.Println("B")
}

func main() {
    a := A{}
    b := B{}

    a.print()  // OUTPUT: A
    b.print()  // OUTPUT: B
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The form `type A = string` creates an alias between the two, they cannot be extended at that stage. What purpose does that solve? Well, for golang they help for certain things like codebase refactoring & repair and there's a great article about it here: https://talks.golang.org/2016/refactor.article.

Type definition allows you to extend a type with some additional behaviour if you require it, this will generally be the one that is most useful as a developer when you want to build custom datatypes from basic datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

### Type Alias

```golang
type A = string
```

This is *alias declaration*. **Alias**, by definition, is *giving another name*. And so, in golang, it this used to give the type (here, 'string') another name (here, 'A'). Then you can define new variables with new alias to that type.
Eg:

```
var myString A
```

### Type Definition

```golang
type A string
```

This is defining a type.
It is very much similar to defining a variable.

```golang
var randomNumber int
```

Here, 'A' is a new type. But you can manipulate the newly defined type A by adding new methods to it.