# How to compare a type defined as a string with a string

Tags: go

I'm working with code that has string constants with a custom type. But when I have an input string, I want to see if this string matches one of the constants. But I'm getting a compilation error that the types are compatible. I've recreated the problem with the code below. Is there a simple way to make this check?

The error I'm getting with this is `invalid operation: compareVal == NamedFoo (mismatched types string and MyFoo)`

The error doesn't make sense to me since MyFoo is defined as a string. I also get more errors trying to cast my constant to a string as in `NamedFoo.(string)`

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyFoo string

const (
    NamedFoo MyFoo = "foobar"
)

func main() {
    compareVal := "foobar"

    if compareVal == NamedFoo {
        fmt.Println("Works")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Didn't Work")
    }
}
```

Comment: `if compareVal == string(NamedFoo) {`

Comment: You could use a type alias instead also, if you don't plan to add new methods on top of `MyFoo`. See [What is the difference between type Declaration and type Definition in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61247864/5291015)

Answer (score 3):

When you do a type definition you are **effectively creating a new type and in go it is not possible to compare different types directly**. If the types are compatible, you can do a conversion to compare comparable values. In this case, you can either convert your `MyFoo` instance to `string` or the `string` to a `MyFoo` instance

Also, it seems like you are confusing type assertions and conversions. Conversions allow to convert between compatible types. Check [this amazing article](https://go101.org/article/value-conversions-assignments-and-comparisons.html) for more information on conversion rules in go. A type assertion allows you to get to the concrete value of an **interface**